# Can PHP command a third party CLI?

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

I want to extend the automation of the PacketETH program CLI using PHP
It can be done in GUI however this still means a user has to do it

Is it possible to have the packetETH run and a PHP deliver instructions, and then receive results back for manipulation?
In a broader sense, is this type of connection possible at all?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can access the command line from php by using the Php System Program Execution functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php. You can try out the exec function. It lets you execute shell commands.

To run the packeteth program from php you can use a command like the following:

exec("/path/to/packeteth/packETHcli -i lo -m 1 -f packet1.pca");